# Is there a way to send WhatsApp messages from desktop / server box?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp

I need online notifications from an enterprise information system.

Exists a way to send messages via WhatsApp instead SMS?

(I work with linux)

I have digging stackoverflow for an answer unsuccessfully.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784395/create-a-web-service-that-can-answer-to-whatsapp-messages?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946461/send-message-by-viber-or-whatsapp-programmatically?rq=1 (now closed)

Comment: @JBCP, my question is older than Qs you references. Duplicates are others ;-)

Comment: That is true enough, I just wanted to make sure they were all linked together. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not official API neither a tool to send messages programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

to send server status to you. pushover alternative: node-xmpp-client with facebook sample and register fake facebook account