# send message by viber or whatsapp programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, whatsapp, viber

I have a system with some members. my members should receive one message each day. I want to send this message via Viber or whatsapp (or if there are others app like them). But I dont want to send messages one by one. I want to send by asp.net c# code. Is there any document or API for this aim?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For **Whatsup** .NET API:

https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet

For **Viber** .NET API:

Couldn't found one for .NET or any other platform.

Comment: Is it legal to use whatsapp for this aim?

Comment: I see no reason why not, I believe Whatsapp would have lock it down if it was a violation from their side.

Comment: @YairNevet There actually where a litle battle http://www.itnetwerk.com/news/2012/09/27/whatsapp-threatens-legal-action-against-api-developers/ between whatsapp and whatsapi dev team, but there is a ceasefire now

Comment: I have recently tried WhatsApp .NET API and my phone number got banned. So I assume that they have way more strict rules in place now.