# How to read answers of the WhatsApp and send them for a Web Service?

Tags: web-services, whatsapp

I would like know if is possible to receive inputs through **whatsapp** app, by the browser, for to process this inputs(message) in an web service.

## Context

John is a chef autonomous, and to do publicity of yours meals through of whatsapp app, in this channel he send daily of meals that will be available of day next, and the peoples that have interested, they go to do one order of type, **yes** or **no**.

I am thinking at to developer a solution that receive inputs of the type **yes** or **no** of the customers through interface of **Whatsapp** web to send this inputs for one web service as the goal of counting the requests done of customers of day before.

My main doubt is if this communication between web service and Whatsapp app can be done or if this of fact is permitted. Up until where I know, many APIs of communication of the app as third-party softwares are not well accepted by the owners the Whatsapp.

My question is, this is possible?, if yes then which is the roads I am should to follow for catch up my goal? someone can give me a light?

#### Some Alternatives

1. Whatsapp business, but still to be fase beta.

   > The problem is that in the region where I am my number not work in the app in fase beta.
2. Exchange for telegram, but the problem is that this customers use in large scale the whatsapp.

This [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22784395/8748688) has similarity with the my, but going by way opposite.